# how to alert the message if the bill no is not in a database

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to alert a message if the bill no is not in the database

```
<form action="<?=site_url('TipUp_Loan/Bill_Delete')?>" class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Bill No: </label>
            <input type="text"  id="bill" class="form-control" name="Search1" autofocus>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer text-center">
        <button type="submit" id="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are You sure want to Delete')" class="btn btn-primary" >Delete<i class="icon-bin position-left"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is view code....

```
public function Bill_Delete(){
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
    $Search = $this->input->post('Search1');
    $this->User_model->Bill_Delete($Search);


}
```

This is a controlller code...

```
public function Bill_Delete($Search)
{

  $this->db->where('billno', $Search);
  $this->db->delete('salesitem');
  $this->db->where('no', $Search);
  $this->db->delete('salesbill');
  //echo "Successfully delted";
  $this->session->set_flashdata('Add', 'You Deleted The Bill No Successfully');

redirect("Inventory/Bill_Entry","refresh");

}
```

This is model code...

my problem is how to find that bill no is present in the database, if it not in the database it should alert the message...

Comment: check using select whether there is the value and delete it, else return error using a flash message or any other convenient way

Comment: how i write in model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$this->db->affected_rows();` function which return true on bill is deleted else false.

Hope this will help.

Comment: we can use this in if conditons

Comment: it is possible to write in alert message

Comment: Yes, you can pass in IF condition.

Comment: possible to alert them

Comment: use roll back and save for concurrent query.

Comment: Yes, If this result return false then set   $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'something went wring ');

Comment: i have wrote this code ,it possible to alert message

Comment: Yes, you can do it in view if the flash session error is isset then show alert

Answer (score 0):

```
        //In controller function
        public function Bill_Delete(){
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('billno','billno','exist[salesitem.billno]');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
            {
                    return $this->set_response( array(), validation_errors(),  'Bill No not exits' );
            }
            else
            {
                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
                $Search = $this->input->post('Search1');
                $this->User_model->Bill_Delete($Search);
            }
        // In MY_Form_validation library
        function exist($str, $value){       

              list($table, $column) = explode('.', $value, 2);    
              $query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM $table WHERE $column = $str'");
              $row = $query->row();

              return ($row->count > 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;

            }
```